# Rails 5 API Token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angular, devise, token

I'm building an API with rails 5 and I want to make token authentication to consomme it with angular 2 as frontend part, I've installed devise for that, I made some research and I'm seeing that all tutorial use devise_token_auth to manage that ! 
can someone one can clarify this point for me ?

when I installed devise gem and test the sign_in route for an admin that I create it with postman, it return some thing like this :

```
"exception": "#<ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError: 822: unexpected token at '------WebKitFormBoundary6qQtmAd3sD9tG4pG\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\nadmin@example.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary6qQtmAd3sD9tG4pG\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\nadmin1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary6qQtmAd3sD9tG4pG--\r\n'>",
```

this the route.rb file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :employes
  devise_for :admins

  namespace :admin do
    resources :vacation_applications
    resources :employes
  end



  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

admin class :

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, #:registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

cans some one guide me to solve that please ?

Comment: It seems your code expects JSON but gets form data and can't parse it

Comment: In postman, try making request by selecting "Body > raw" and enter your params as a valid JSON there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to post man and select **Body** then select **raw** radio button. There will be a drop down just beside the **binary** radio button on the same window. Click and select **JSON(application/json)**.

Below you will find a text box after selecting **raw**. Insert a valid json payload to send as parameter.

Example:

```
{

 "user_email": "test@gmail.com",
 "password": "abc"

}
```